# How to use search filters in Laravel Orchid while having multiple tables in the same screen?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, orchid

Using Orchid Laravel Http Filter you will be able to search for defind columns in allowedFilters, and this will pass the values to defind filter method.

while having multiple tables in the same screen this will make the Http Filter passed for all tables in the screen since the filters parameters are not defind with the model/table name.

`filter[status][]=1`

in the above filter request the status filter will be for all tables in the screen that has the `status` column, is it possible to pass model/table name in the Http Filter to distinguish the targeted table.